# How come Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya does not mention Islam?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, brahma-sutras, other-religions, ramanujacharya, islam

Chapter 2 of Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya, which is his commentary on the Brahma Sutars, attempts to refute all other opposing philosophical schools that don't adhere to Vishishtadvaita Vedanta, such as Buddhism, Jainism, Advaita Vedanta, Shaivism, Shaktism, Sankhya, and Vaisheshika.

But how come he doesn't mention Islam, since Islam had entered India by the 1100s?

Comment: Islam did not enter South India during the 1100s

Comment: It was there in North India and Ramanuja even spoke to a Muslim king

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Yes, as Ikshvaku says Ramanujacharya went to the Sultan of Delhi to retrieve the processional idol of the Cheluva Narayana temple in Melkote, Karnataka, which the Muslims had stolen.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Well, Ramanujacharya, like other commentators on the Brahma Sutras, mainly focuses on refuting the rival philosophical schools that existed in Vyasa's time, since the point is to elaborate on Vyasa's refutations.  There are some exceptions to that, like Adi Shankaracharya refuting Bhatrihari's philosophy of Sphotavada, and all commentators refuting rival Vedantic philosophies, but I don't know of any commentary on the Brahma Sutras which refutes Mleccha religions.  They're focused on refuting Astika and Nastika philosophies, i.e. philosophies indigenous to India.

Comment: @Ikshvaku One possible reason for that is that Mlecchas may not have been involved in the intellectual debate in ancient/medieval India.  I'm of course aware of violent conflicts between Hindus and Muslims, but I'm not aware of any philosophical debates between Hindus and Mlecchas earlier than a century or two ago.

Comment: I can ask the same question for post-Ramanujacharya's commentaries as well.

Comment: I just posted a follow-up to your question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21951/36

Comment: At that time muslim rule was happening.. to refute Muslim philosophy is punished with death penalty There is no question of discussion.. Muslim rule is simple all infidel are already dead they ready to be killed as animal (concept)